# Very challenging network access problem: can't browse but can ping. Other PCs can browse and ping

Tags: windows-xp

**I decided to reinstall Windows** from scratch. This PC was about 4 years old and is due for a reinstall anyway.

So unfortunately **I can't try out some of the great suggestions below.**

I've got a weird problem that perhaps someone can provide insight to.

On my server none of the web browsers will browse the Internet (to say google.com) or even to an IP address. In Internet Explorer 6 I just get "The page cannot be displayed".

However, I CAN PING Google.com and get a reply. It was working a few months ago last time I needed to browse the web from the server.

Another Windows PC (these are all Windows XP Professional) connected to one of the other 3 LAN ports on the same router and can access the Internet (browsing, etc.) just fine.

I've tried turning off the Windows Firewall (although no changes have been made to it).
I've checked the router it's connected to and there's nothing configured for specific IP addresses.

Configuration:

```
CableModem -> WRT54G Router 
              - PC 1
              - PC 2
              - old WRTG54G router (being used as bridge)
                    -PC 3 - Browses the web just fine.
                    -Server - Can NOT browse the Web. Can Ping google.com
```

The router doesn't have anything special configured for that PC's IP address (*.107).
I've checked the HOSTS file on the server and it lists only:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  (which is for local web server stuff).
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you telnet to google.com port 80?  Can you do a manual HTTP GET request by typing `GET / HTTP/1.0` and then pressing enter twice?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your proxy settings to see if you're going through a different server for HTTP on Internet Explorer?

If so, make sure the host you're going to is available.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into a similar problem.  I have no idea what caused it but removing the NIC and related drivers and re-installing them fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Microsoft knowledge base article *[How to determine and to recover from Winsock2 corruption in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, and in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259)*.

I had this same problem once where all TCP connections were dead, but `ping` and `nslookup` still worked. It took me a couple of days to finally fix it. I can't remember exactly what fixed it, but I know I copied my `tcpip.sys` and other network drivers over from another machine and replaced them using the recovery console.

I am not sure if the initial problem was just a random corruption or if it was some kind of malware.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) to trace network activity (packets), and maybe find out what's going on.

As you said "none of my browsers..." I guess you not only tried Internet Explorer. From a command line, you can try: `telnet www.google.com 80`

If you have a black screen, then the network connectivity is there. It's something in Windows that blocks traffic (antivirus or firewall?).

The basic debug process: reboot, check for viruses and trojans, and apply updates.